# Can I use 'Fortunately' in an academic paper

Tags: writing, writing-style

When using "Fortunately" in a technical paper, the appending statement can appear subjective; and hence shouldn't be used in an academic context (?). When used to highlight, for instance, the solution to a potential problem:

*"Thing X must be able to do difficult task Y. **Fortunately**, many existing solutions are available that can do task Y"*

It seems to me than the subjectivity of 'fortunately' actually depends on context. If task Y is something controversial, such as drone strikes against military hospitals (to take a very extreme example), then the statement following 'Fortunately' can seem perverse to many: It comes across as if the author is in moral agreement of performing task Y.

Now imagine if task Y is something harmless, such as "the envisioned calculator must be able to store user preferences between power cycles.". In this case, 'Fortunately' is a very applicable adverb to use: "Fortunately, many cheap forms of solid state storage are commercially available in the target form factor."

Can I/Is it safe to use 'Fortunately' in an academic paper?

Comment: I think it's fine. In your example, "Fortunately, many cheap forms of solid state storage are commercially available in the target form factor" I think the word "fortunately" adds clarity.

Comment: If you like, you can begin a sentence with: "Fortunately for thing X, all obstacles were removed and a task Y was ...."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you, yourself, question the usage, then you should probably avoid it.

I think that in the present case, if you need a bridging word, then "However" works just as well.

In general it is probably a bad idea to ban any given word, not knowing all possible contexts in which it might be used.

That said, I find no problem with using "Fortunately" in this context. It is, indeed, fortunate that the times and the work of others have come together to provide us with ways to a solution of the problem at hand. In other times it might not have been possible, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but in the interest of brevity, I suggest leaving it out.  There's no clear benefit to using the word.